# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow using eventRegister.exe

Tags: c#, etw, etw-eventsource

I'm trying to compile a simple project with ETW logs. Have added EventSource as NuGet reference. When I had `Event` attributes like this

> [Event(1, Message = "Something happend in base at begin: {0}")]

It wasn't working, but at least it was successfully compiling. Then I changed the attribute and it became like this

> [Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Error, Message = "Base stp {0}", Keywords = EventKeywords.All)]

And I started to get

> Unexpected error: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

1. Is there a way to fix it and don't change the structure of my classes?
2. Is there a way to debug or at least somehow investigate errors from eventRegister.exe?

My command line is:

> Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Console1\packages\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.1.1.28\build\eventRegister.exe" -DumpRegDlls @"Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Console1\Common\bin\Debug\Common.eventRegister.rsp" "Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Console1\Common\bin\Debug\Common.dll"

Code of the test example could be found [here](https://github.com/CassandraDied/EventSourceExample).

Comment: try a EventSource class without implementing an Interface

Comment: @magicandre1981, but I need this interface.

Comment: why is this interface important? try it without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the issue is the use of "Keywords = EventKeywords.All" in the event definition. EventKeywords.All is not intended for use in events. It means "all 64 keywords", which is actually illegal since the top bits are reserved. The EventKeywords.All value is defined for convenience when setting up event listeners or when checking for event masks, but shouldn't be used when defining events. In this case, EventRegister wasn't expecting events to use that for the Keywords value so it was hitting an exception. (This would have had problems at runtime as well since EventSource would have complained about the use of reserved keywords.)

Are you making use of the manifest that EventRegister creates? The EventRegister tool reflects over your assembly and generates a manifest file for each class in your assembly that inherits from EventSource. If you aren't using the manifest it generates, you don't need to run it. There are several things that can confuse the EventRegister tool and cause it to fail.

If you aren't using the manifest, you can disable EventRegister in your .csproj file, or you can have your project depend on "EventSource Redistributable" instead of "EventSource", which will give you access to the EventSource DLL without adding EventRegister to the build process.

Note also that EventSource is built-in to .NET 4.5 and later -- you only need the NuGet if you need to run your project on an older .NET runtime. The built-in version performs MUCH faster as well (since it doesn't need to JIT as much -- all of the built-in runtime DLLs get JIT'ed during install).

One final note is that the .NET 4.6 and the NuGet 1.1.24 and later versions of EventSource have a "manifest-free" option that eliminates the manifest entirely. They also have an eventSource.Write method that allows you to write events directly without having to keep track of event IDs. So instead of:

```
[EventSource]
class MyEventSource : EventSource
{
    [Event(...)]
    public void MyEvent(...)
    {
        WriteEvent(...);
    }
}

es = new MyEventSource();
es.MyEvent(23, "Hello");
```

You can just do this:

```
es = new EventSource("MyEventSourceName");
es.Write("MyEvent", new {
    Number = 23,
    Name = "Hello"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. Unfortunately, no, I can't write like this. I need the complex structure (with interfaces and inheritance) that I have in the example; it is a part of my project's architecture. I really don't need manifest file(I don't use channels), but I need compile time checks on correctness of definition of my events. And I'm using NuGet package exactly because of these checks(and because of inheritance). Will they still be presented if I disable manifest generation?

Comment: I'm not sure what checks you are getting from the NuGet package. The NuGet package does run EventRegister to generate the manifest, but as you have seen, EventRegister can be confused by perfectly valid code. In addition, EventRegister probably won't detect many of the potential coding problems, so I'm not sure that EventRegister is providing any benefit. EventRegister is intended for generating manifests at compile time, not for performing any tests. Unless you are using the manifest, you shouldn't use EventRegister.

Comment: there are checks like that your Keyword number should be a power of two or that your EvenSource derived class should be sealed and it generates compile time errors if it isn't. Have you seen something like this?

Comment: Looking a bit more closely at your code, the issue is with EventKeywords.All. Your event should not use this value. If you want the event to fire regardless of keyword, just leave Keyword unset.

Comment: but why I should not use this value? 32 is power of 2. I have not seen any other restrictions on these values. Is there any?

Comment: EventKeywords.All means all 64 bits are set. It is not 32 and it is not a power of 2. The All value is not for use with events. It exists for use when configuring a listened or when checking whether an EventSource has certain bits enabled in its configuration.